# Приоритет наложения слоёв

Tags: css, css3, вёрстка

Есть блок который находится под заголовком, заголовок налаживается поверх него, но нужно чтобы абзац внутри блока налаживался поверх заголовка. Такое реально реализовать?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;  
}

div {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: gray;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

h1 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    border: 1px black solid;
    width: 500px;
    left: 0;
}

p {
    text-align: right;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
 <body>
     <h1>Этот мешает</h1>
     <div>
     <p>Я хочу скопировать этот текст</p>
     </div>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

В вашем примере `div` сравнивается по z-index с `h1`, и все внутренние элементы в `div` получают в этом сравнении `z-index: 1`. А `z-index: 3` уже идут для сравнения элементов внутри `div`. Я бы убрал у `div` `position: absolute;` тогда `div` будет считаться обычным элементом и сравниваться с `h1` будут уже дочерние элементы:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;  
}
div{
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: gray;
    top: 0;
}
h1{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    border: 1px black solid;
    width: 500px;
    left: 0px;
}
p{
    text-align: right;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
 <body>
     <h1>Этот мешает</h1>
     <div>
     <p>Я хочу скопировать этот текст</p>
     </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: Всё гениально просто

Comment: @Crantisz Да, всё спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Можно установить для заголовка [`pointer-events:none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: gray;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
h1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  border: 1px black solid;
  width: 500px;
  left: 0px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
p {
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Этот мешает</h1>
  <div>
    <p>Я хочу скопировать этот текст</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Простите, но это костыль

Comment: @Yuri, но это работает, и даже, вероятно, так как хочет автор.

Comment: @Grundy Но тогда h1 не будет копироваться

Comment: @PeGaS, будет. Просто его выделение будет не совсем тривиальным